# Изменить переменную

Tags: delphi, переменные

Добрый вечер! Можно ли в уже скомпилированной программе без перекомпиляции изменить значение какой-нибудь переменной на другое и сохранить его в этом же .exe файле.

Comment: лично мне непонятно что означает сохранить в тот-же .exe файл..<br>
Ну да собственно суть коммента не в этом, вопрос в другом - ЗАЧЕМ ВАМ ЭТО?

Comment: Просто надо усложнить шифр и хочу, чтобы после 3-х попыток значение переменной менялось на false например и прога не запускалась.

Comment: Лениво писать "балладу", напишу коротко - не в ту сторону копаете...

Comment: Безусловно, такой подход не совсем удачный, но если еще прибавить к нему конфигурацию системы? Я хочу это сделать как дополнительную защиту к не всегда стойким алгоритмам.

Comment: "сохранить"? То что вы описали легко обходится созданием копии ещё незалоченной версии программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о константе, которая жестко прошита в бинарник, то ее можно изменить, пропатчив бинарник на требуемое значение, определив то место в exe-файле, где она находится.

Comment: Ну она не константа, а мб изменяемая со временем.

Answer (score -1):

Да.
Например числовая переменная - a.

Меняем её например через edit:

```
a:= StrToInt (edit1.text);
```

И потом сохранить это значение с помощью ini файла и выгружать его при запуске программы.
Надеюсь как делать ини писать не нужно. В Интернете туториалов полно.

Цели такой шняги могут быть разными -  например через такие переменные патроны в своей игре сохраняю.

Comment: и где тут "в этом же .exe файле"? :)